# Is there a way to customise the y-axis labels of line chart based on the given coordinates in chat.js?

Tags: javascript, charts, frontend, chart.js, finance

I'm plotting a revenue-time chart of a company.

Given a list of y-coordinates that represent value of revenue of a company over a period of time, how do I set the labels of the y-axis in a much readable manner than the default?

The revenue data (y-coordinates):

```
const revenueData = [227223.0, 294011.0, 263676.0, 199686.0, 289792.0, 224023.0, 253386.0, 269343.0, 324612.0, 220999.0];
```

The corresponding times (x-coordinates):

```
const xAxisLabels = ["Q4 FY20","Q1 FY21","Q2 FY21","Q3 FY21","Q4 FY21","Q1 FY22","Q2 FY22","Q3 FY22","Q4 FY22","Q1 FY23"];
```

Based on the above `revenueData` the y-axis labels are as seen in the screenshot below:
[image]

Instead of displaying labels in the above format `350,000` and `200,000` I would like to display them as `350K` and `200K`, the format being the abbreviated version. Similar to the drawing below:
[image: drawing]

How do I achieve this?

Ideally, instead of hard-coding the label values in the mentioned format, the code must be able to configure it based on the y-coordinates given.

Here's my full JS code:

```
const revenueData = [227223.0, 294011.0, 263676.0, 199686.0, 289792.0, 224023.0, 253386.0, 269343.0, 324612.0, 220999.0];

const xAxisLabels = ["Q4 FY20","Q1 FY21","Q2 FY21","Q3 FY21","Q4 FY21","Q1 FY22","Q2 FY22","Q3 FY22","Q4 FY22","Q1 FY23"];  

const chartData = {
   labels: xAxisLabels,
   datasets: [{
      yAxisID: 'revenueAxis',              
      label: 'Revenue JPY',
      data: revenueData,
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'red',
      backgroundColor: 'red'
   }],
};

const chartConfig = {
   type: "line",
   data: chartData,
   options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
         revenueAxis: {
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'left',
            grid: { display: false },
            ticks: { color: 'red', },
            font: { family: "Garamond",},
            title: {
               text: 'Revenue in JPY',
               display: true
            }
         },
         x: {
            grid: { display: false }
         }
      },
      plugins: {
         legend: { display: false },
         title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Custom Chart Title',
            font: {
               size: 20,
               weight: 'normal',
            },
            padding: {
               top: 10,
               bottom: 30
            }
         }, 
      },
   }
};

const newChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chartContainer'), chartConfig);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize your y-axis labels like this:

```js
const chartConfig = {
   type: "line",
   data: chartData,
   options: {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      scales: {
         revenueAxis: {
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'left',
            grid: { display: false },
            ticks: { 
               color: 'red', 
               callback: (value) => {
                   return value / 1000 + 'k';
               },
            },
            font: { family: "Garamond",},
            title: {
               text: 'Revenue in JPY',
               display: true
            }
         },
         x: {
            grid: { display: false }
         },

...rest of code
```

The callback function gets the value of each label and returns that divided by 1000 and adds the letter "k" at the end. (If the value somehow gets passed as a string, add a "+" in front of *value*)

Comment: Yes you are right. I totally missed that. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I don't quite understand how it's possible to perform a maths calculation when `value` is a string as we can perform string concatenation.

Comment: @space-ninja-x If ```value``` is a string but you know it is a number (like in your case revenue), you can add a "+" in front of value to make it a number to perform the calculation.

You can concatenate numbers with strings.